# Error With XmlDocument.load causing ntdll.dll error on exit of aplication

Tags: c#, runtime-error, xmldocument, ntdll

So I have a problem with the xmldocument.load function [MSND Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/875kz807%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) . Specifically, it runs fine in the code but upon closing the program it causes an error in ntdll.dll.

[Picture of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRmno.png)

However, if I remove this function from the program I’m writing and run it separately it works without error. Also if I run the rest of my program with some dummy input it runs and closes without error as well.

To be clear this is running as a windows forms application with these functions being called from a google API library I’m putting together.

```
public static string Test()
    {
        XmlDocument XML = new XmlDocument();
        XML.Load(@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?units=imperial&origins=Vancouver+BC|Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco|Vancouver+BC&key=AIzaSyA_j0g3zKKhosZz9uEXwCWd2fuv3WCwHPk");
        string S = XML.ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[3].ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[0].InnerText;
        return S;
    }
```

How would I Resolve this error message?

Sense it dose not appear to be causing issues with the program I would also accept a way to suppress the error message from popping up after the program closes. Though obviously I would prefer to fix the issue than just cover it up.

Edit: 4/18/2016
I just made one of my first Alpha testing builds of the program and when the program is being run from outside of Visual studio after using WIX to create an installer and install it it is not throwing the error. still acting up from within visual studio though very odd.

Comment: I might be wrong, but as I remember error ..00008 was sth like "file does not exist on disk" error. Are you sure you can feed a url to Load function, I would say it asks for an actual file on disk.

Comment: Sounds like an old COM memory leak symptom (DLL errors on app close), but as I recall the XML Document isn't disposable.  Maybe use process monitor or similar to be sure there's no hanging references to the dll?

Comment: If you read the text at the start of the msdn page it specifically says that it can load from a url. Also the code runs and retrieves the xml information properly.